# Javascript Type Mismatch for Removing an Item for Select

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

```
<select id="myId">
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

and in Javascript I am trying to remove item index 1 programmatically:

```
function remove() {
     var doc = document.getElementById('myId'); 
     doc.removeChild(doc.childNodes[1]);
}
```

but I am getting "Type mismatch" error in removeChild() in IE11. I can only use Javascript.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The result of getElementById is note a node list thus the type error.
Try changing

`document.getElementById('myId');`

to

`document.querySelector('#myId');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `childNodes[1]` refers to `textNode`. So try `querySelector` and `nth-child`

```js
function remove() {
  var option = document.querySelector('#myId option:nth-child(1)');
  option.parentNode.removeChild(option);
}
remove()
```

```html
<select id="myId">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```